# DevExpress Spell Checker: Is there an easy (built-in) way to propagate spell checker options updates?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, spell-checking

I have an application that contains multiple MemoEdit controls containing DevExpress spell checkers. When a user updates the Options (through a MemoEdit's context menu), we are saving those options to our db. Is there any built-in way to broadcast those new options to all spell checkers in the application? It's probably worth noting that some of the MemoEdits are used in Interop controls in the VB6 "part" of our application.

Right now I'm using events, but things aren't working out as well as I'd hoped and before I get too deeply into rolling my own fix I figured I'd ask the SO folks.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tech lead and I just acquired dev express subscription for a win forms application we are building and we are using the spellchecker and saving the options to our sql server ce table. We have multiple forms with one spellchecker each tied to one memo edit control per form.
I programmed a single reusable function named “GetSpellCheckerOptions” which returns type “DevExpress.ExtraSpellChecker.OptionsSpelling” that loads the six options from the spell check options dialog form from our sql server ce table. This function is invoked in a form’s constructor where the form has the spellchecker component associated to it and this can be any form in our application. It is built around an “on-demand” basis as opposed to loading it in memory and keeping it around for the lifetime of the application because the notes or comments being written by our users are on forms that load, fill it out and close.
You can use the event called OptionsChanged which is a member of the type “DevExpress.ExtraSpellChecker.OptionsSpelling”. You will have hook up the event in runtime using a subroutine you write like this for example:

```
jobsSpellChecker.OptionsSpelling.OptionChanged += new EventHandler(this.jobsSpellChecker_OptionChanged);
```

When a user changes an option on the spell check options dialog this event will fire, however there are some gotchas to be aware of. When the event fires you will not know which option fired the event because the Event Argument does not provide that information. So I save as a whole save regardless of which options were changed. The save occurs after the OK button is clicked as opposed per option being changed. The biggest gotcha is that this event fires three times. Two of those three times is from something totally unrelated to changing an option. So to control the two unneed event fires you need an if statement evaluating the options form dialog result, like this for example,

```
if(jobsSpellChecker.FormsManager.OptionsForm.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
```

This will protect your save code from being executed needlessly. In addition without the “if” statement the control has a nasty way of remembering previous state of what the options were before you changed them and during those unneeded two of three event fires, it changes your options setting from the new desired settings back to previous state or settings. Very annoying and it has taken the whole day to get past these obstacles and more experimenting with these controls. Hopefully this information can offer you or someone else a value that will save time, avoid potential frustration and endless browsing product support pages.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your approach sounds similar to what I eventually went with. We were using Event Broker to broadcast changes, with the presenters on the .NET side of our app listening for options updates, then updating their respective views as needed. We were running into threading issues, though, on the VB6 side of things, to which we propagated the events. I'm no longer with the company, though, and can't remember the specifics.